# Python, lambda, find minimum

Tags: python, lambda

I have foreach function which calls specified function on every element which it contains. I want to get minimum from thise elements but I have no idea how to write lambda or function or even a class that would manage that.
Thanks for every help.

---

I use my foreach function like this:

```
o.foreach( lambda i: i.call() )
```

or

```
o.foreach( I.call )
```

I don't like to make a lists or other objects. I want to iterate trough it and find min.

I manage to write a class that do the think but there should be some better solution than that:

```
class Min:                                           
    def __init__(self,i):                        
        self.i = i                              
    def get_min(self):                               
        return self.i                                
    def set_val(self,o):                             
        if o.val < self.i: self.i = o.val

m = Min( xmin )
self.foreach( m.set_val )                            
xmin = m.get_min()
```

---

Ok, so I suppose that my .foreach method is non-python idea. I should do my Class iterable because all your solutions are based on lists and then everything will become easier.

In C# there would be no problem with lambda function like that, so I though that python is also that powerful.

Comment: Can you please post some example code of what you've got so far?

Comment: +1 for the possible-homework tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing `foreach` method is not very pythonic. You should better make it an iterator so that it works with standard python functions like `min`.

Instead of writing something like this:

```
def foreach(self, f):
    for d in self._data:
        f(d)
```

write this:

```
def __iter__(self):
    for d in self._data:
        yield d
```

Now you can call `min` as `min(myobj)`.

Comment: But how that works when I break an iteration and start it again?
It starts from the begin or from the moment it was broken?

Comment: It calls the `__iter__` function again and that returns a fresh iterator over the entire data.

Answer (score 13):

Python has built-in [support for finding minimums](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min):

```
>>> min([1, 2, 3])
1
```

If you need to process the list with a function first, you can do that with [map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> def double(x):
...    return x * 2
... 
>>> min(map(double, [1, 2, 3]))
2
```

Or you can get fancy with [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [generator expressions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions), for example:

```
>>> min(double(x) for x in [1, 2, 3])
2
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't do this with `foreach` and a lambda. If you want to do this in a functional style without actually using `min`, you'll find `reduce` is pretty close to the function you were trying to define.

```
l = [5,2,6,7,9,8]
reduce(lambda a,b: a if a < b else b, l[1:], l[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, one thing you need to understand: `lambda` creates a function object for you.  But so does plain, ordinary `def`.  Look at this example:

```
lst = range(10)

print filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, lst)

def is_even(x):
    return x % 2 == 0

print filter(is_even, lst)
```

Both of these work.  They produce the same identical result.  `lambda` makes an un-named function object; `def` makes a named function object.  `filter()` doesn't care whether the function object has a name or not.

So, if your only problem with `lambda` is that you can't use `=` in a `lambda`, you can just make a function using `def`.

Now, that said, I don't suggest you use your `.foreach()` method to find a minimum value.  Instead, make your main object return a list of values, and simply call the Python `min()` function.

```
lst = range(10)
print min(lst)
```

EDIT: I agree that the answer that was accepted is better.  Rather than returning a list of values, it is better to define `__iter__()` and make the object iterable.

Answer (score 1):

> I have foreach function which calls specified function on every element which it contains

It sounds, from the comment you subsequently posted, that you have re-invented the built-in `map` function.

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```
min(map(f, seq))
```

where `f` is the function that you want to call on every item in the list.

As gnibbler shows, if you want to find the value `x` in the sequence for which `f(x)` returns the lowest value, you can use:

```
min(seq, key=f)
```

...unless you want to find *all* of the items in `seq` for which `f` returns the lowest value.  For instance, if `seq` is a list of dictionaries,

```
min(seq, key=len)
```

will return the first dictionary in the list with the smallest number of items, not all dictionaries that contain that number of items.

To get a list of all items in a sequence for which the function `f` returns the smallest value, do this:

```
values = map(f, seq)
result = [seq[i] for (i, v) in enumerate(values) if v == min(values)]
```

Comment: You should evaluate the minimum only once before the list comprehension instead of evaluating it over and over each iteration inside the list comprehension. Apart from that, it's a fine answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have

```
>>> seq = range(-4,4)
>>> def f(x):
...  return x*x-2
```

for the minimum value of f

```
>>> min(f(x) for x in seq)
-2
```

for the value of x at the minimum

```
>>> min(seq, key=f)
0
```

of course you can use lambda too

```
>>> min((lambda x:x*x-2)(x) for x in range(-4,4))
-2
```

but that is a little ugly, map looks better here

```
>>> min(map(lambda x:x*x-2, seq))
-2

>>> min(seq,key=lambda x:x*x-2)
0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
x = lambda x,y,z: min(x,y,z)
print(x(3,2,1))
```